# Xamarin Forms: save camera image to external storage

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, android-camera, android-external-storage

I'm developing an application using Xamarin Forms, I'm using this [MediaPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) to capture image and store it in the device. What I want is to store the captured image in the external storage (external SD Card), here is my code, it stores the images in a folder created in the local storage when the application installed. I tried to change the directory line to

```
Directory = "/storage/extSdCard/ImagesFolder/",
```

but his creates a local folder with name storageextSdCardImagesFolder

is there any idea how to store the image in external storage? I'm only interested in Android device.

```C#
private async void takePhotoBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
       if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
       {
           await DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":(No camera available.", "OK");
           return;
       }

       _mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
       {
           Directory = "ImagesFolder",
           Name = _farmId + ".jpg"
       });

       if (_mediaFile == null)
           return;
       FileImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
       {
           var stream = _mediaFile.GetStream();
           _mediaFile.Dispose();
           return stream;
       });
   }
```